# Calculate bar numbers and the total number of bars in the stacked bar chart

Tags: vega-lite

How to get bar# ( and then the total number of bars) in the stacked bar chart?
I tried dense_rank window function, but it didn't work.

```json
    {
      "data": {
        "values": [
          {"DATE": "2020-02-02", "Category": "AA", "Value": 50},
          {"DATE": "2020-02-02", "Category": "BB", "Value": 50},
          {"DATE": "2020-02-03", "Category": "AA", "Value": 70},
          {"DATE": "2020-02-03", "Category": "BB", "Value": 100},
          {"DATE": "2020-02-04", "Category": "AA", "Value": 110},
          {"DATE": "2020-02-04", "Category": "BB", "Value": 140},
          {"DATE": "2020-02-05", "Category": "AA", "Value": 150},
          {"DATE": "2020-02-05", "Category": "BB", "Value": 190},
          {"DATE": "2020-02-06", "Category": "AA", "Value": 200},
          {"DATE": "2020-02-06", "Category": "BB", "Value": 250}
        ]
      },
      "transform": [
        {"window": [{"op": "dense_rank", "as": "BarNo"}], "sortby": ["DATE"]}
      ],
      "encoding": {
        "x": {"field": "DATE", "type": "nominal"},
        "y": {"field": "Value", "aggregate": "sum", "type": "quantitative"}
      },
      "layer": [
        {"mark": "bar", "encoding": {"color": {"field": "Category"}}},
        {
          "mark": {"type": "text", "dy": -5},
          "encoding": {
            "text": {"field": "BarNo", "aggregate": "min", "type": "quantitative"}
          }
        }
      ]
    }
```

[Vega Editor](https://vega.github.io/editor/#/url/vega-lite/N4IgJghgLhIFygG4QDYFcCmBneBtUAIgIIAqAovCAEwAMtAtHY1SADQgDC0GA5gPYAnAJ6UiRNiABqqTPACsNAL6tCpCnGp0azZhK5RegkRoBCJidPQZ5SlSGLlKtBkxoBmPd37DR49pdk4AHZbVUcNZ21XD3Z9Qx9Tc38ZazgARhpQ+zUnLR0aABZPA29jEDELFPg0jOUw9U0XKkYi2K8jSjNKq2qCrIcGyPy5YviyiuSe9IU67PDGqOaaEbaSjsTuwLSATn6ciLzXADZR0t9N1No9+aHj0-WQLsnAqhmAXWUQKAEIADssABmggAtnhQAB3ACWvzAfHBYJAfAADpQwBh-hgAPo-X4AawkEBwpggAgAcnwQIo3uwsIIoAAjYy4OYUD7UkDogDGfDA0J48FAAA8BSAAZCMCgwJQBhIoEIkakQL8+MDoahKexjKAxRKpRoAtZ2BAeDwBLxuJQsGhQew5QrKABHNB-KCQmCuxDWRSfFAQIQYAQI4Ek-EaekkiRcnl8kXclCCEU6yWUOJnb2zYMCUOgO2KgyCqASMDGehyT5R3m-fkIL4YAuJ8XJ4lkilGk1mngWjSq36y+WKp0ut3QSGeynej5AA)

[image: Bar Charts w. bar # as labels]

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Never mind. Here is a solution:

```json
      "transform": [
        {"window": [{
          "op":"distinct", 
          "field":"DATE",
          "as": "BarNo"}],
          "sortby": ["DATE"],
          "frame": [null,0]
        },
        {
          "joinaggregate": [{
            "op":"max",
            "field": "BarNo",
            "as": "BarCount"
          }]
        }
      ]
```

[Vega-lite Editor](https://vega.github.io/editor/#/url/vega-lite/N4IgJghgLhIFygG4QDYFcCmBneBtUAIgIIAqAovCAEwAMtAtHY1SADQgDC0GA5gPYAnAJ6UiRNiABqqTPACsNAL6tCpCnGp0azZhK5RegkRoBCJidPQZ5SlSGLlKtBkxoBmPd37DR49pdk4AHZbVUcNZ21XD3Z9Qx9Tc38ZazgARhpQ+zUnLR0aABZPA29jEDELFPg0jOUw9U0XKkYi2K8jSjNKq2qCrIcGyPy5YviyiuSe9IU67PDGqOaaEbaSjsTuwLSATn6ciLzXADZR0t9N1No9+aHj0-WQLsnAqhmAXWUQKAEIADssABmggAtnhQAB3ACWvzAfHBYJAfAADpQwJCsFBoQBjKASAGQjAoMCUAYSCA4UwQAQAOT4IEUb3YWEEUAARsZcHMKIyQACfsDUrhfmgUChWDQPnYAFZ8aEQHg8AS8bgI5GUYEQAAeeIJRM6VNpZIpjypHD4aF+uIZDPYGF+WL4aN+PHgoG1CF5uuJGlJ7CgQiRqRAvz4wLlKHp7GMoHxhO9Uiq7HliuVBkoWDQoL9AaDAEc0H9MTBMYhrIpPigIEIMAIERqBABrSisqkSO0Op0uj0OlCCV2euOUOJncuzetNj3+wOUAya3HsMDGehyT7tx3QrugWe4j2xvWUml0pMKpU8FUaMO-CRTvMFy2Q4uQ0v08sfIA)

[image]

[image]